# Objective-C variable out of scope

Tags: objective-c, scope

I am having an issue with a variable being labeled as "out of scope".

The following method can be found in my code:

```
- (void)CampaignComplete:(Campaign *)controller Picked:(NSString *)value {
    selectedCampaign = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: value];
```

The value of variable named "value" can be seen by the debugger.  However, when I assign it to the variable selectedCampaign and continue stepping through the program selectedCampaign becomes out of scope.

Here are selectedCampaign stuff from the .h:

```
@interface .....{
    NSString *selectedCampaign;
}
@property (retain) NSString *selectedCampaign;
@end
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the ..... object still in scope? Has its dealloc method been called and released selectedCampaign?

Comment: This is the only place in the program that it has been used in.

Comment: Yeah, but if you've alloc'ed and retained a "....." object, then called CampaignComplete, then released the ..... object, and if in the dealloc method of ..... you release selectedCampagn (as you should), then selectedCampaign will be out of scope. Are you sure the ..... object is still alive?

Comment: Yes I am entirely certain that the object is not being dealloc.  The parent class is in use and has never been dealloc at any point.

Comment: Found out something weird... all of the other member variables are also coming up as out of scope inside of this method.  This is an event that is being raised from a different class... could that be why?

Comment: Aww I figured it out... using the self keyword gave me viewable access to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using self.selectedCampaign cleared up the issue... it is now in scope for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You are referring entirely to debug time "in scope" vs. "out of scope" issues and not compile time, right?

If so, the issue is a known bug in the debugger that is fixed in a later release. I'm not sure if the bug fix is in a shipping version of the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think the data in string value , is not in string format